# Timeout Before Writing the Password In TELNETLIB

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am trying to telnet to a device with ip.

```
import telnetlib
deviceIp = '192.168.1.135'
password1='xxxxxx'
telnetConeection = telnetlib.Telnet(deviceIp,23)
telnetConeection.read_until(b'Password: ')
telnetConeection.write(password1.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
telnetConeection.write(b'\n')
telnetConeection.write(b'port\n')
print(telnetConeection.read_all())
```

The ouput as : **b'Timeout!\n'**

It is clear  that :-

- the connection to device is made
- the script is reading till 'Password'

What is not clear to me is that :why the write password is not working and timeout is happening?
Kindly help me out.

**Any suggestion will be highly appreciated !**

Comment: So password comes up or not? Are you sure you have the port open (`23`)?

Comment: Yes when I am executing telnet 192.168.1.135 23 on terminal ,it is working fine ! The output is  : b'Timeout!\n' on executing above

Comment: Can you post the connection log perhaps?

Comment: sorry! did not implement any logging here though !sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I would imagine it's something basic in the script causing the timeout; which platform are you attempting to run this on? Maybe [try this script](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/b5ccb82559c932543e83c406b92fabee) and see if you can successfully connect (it reveals very useful debugging information), to use (`python telnetlib.py -d "hostname"`)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response! I am using Ubuntu 18.04. The above script you mentioned has hanged since executing it quite some time ago!It's hanged still ! no response

Comment: You’re welcome! To determine if it’s a host or client side issue maybe try another telnet host such as “rainmaker.wunderground.com” to see if it will connect.

Comment: Hi,the host you mentioned was not working for me.But,I successfully got response from india.colorado.edu port 13 (the time as the response) through python

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose the answer is as simple as increasing your timeout? Maybe the other end is slow?

```
timeout=30
telnetConeection.read_until(b'Password: ', timeout)
```

<strike>Also, you should probably double check everything the other end is sending you. Maybe the other end isn't even sending you anything (which would point to a different problem).</strike> Looks like you've tested that and you're getting what you expect.

ALSO, Telnet.expect might give you more information on your errors (ie EOF? Nothing matched?)